# Invisible $\LaTeX$ error: $\mathrm{Im} \left( \right) $ vs. $\mathrm{Im} \left( \r ​ight) $

Tags: bug, mathjax

The following tex works fine, when I write it myself:

$\mathrm{Im} \left(  \right) $,

but when I copy the same tex from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203453/is-this-fourier-like-transform-equal-to-the-riemann-zeta-function#comment463598_203453) it doesn't work:

$\mathrm{Im} \left(  \r‌​ight) $

Why is that? And you might have noticed the different look in title and post. It was just a copy-paste. Are they rendered differently?

**EDIT**

I put this in a comment below:

\$\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\$

thats 589 characters plain tex and 91 when it's tex-ed

$\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$

First of all it doesn't fit to martin suggestion of $>80$ chars without white space,
second it totally break the page layout and third it doesn't work there...

Comment: Funny after posting it, the title seems to reveal it. But have a look at the [edit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/8355/edit). It does show up there...

Comment: Probably the same problem as http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3953/ Mats's comment contains a TeX string of length $> 80$ without whitespace. The two invisible unicode characters `0x200c` and `0x200b` are inserted at position 79.

Comment: @Martin: good catch. Since this was isolated (probably by the copy-paste), I didn't think of that. It is the same problem. Add spaces to long (>80 character) LaTeX strings with no breaks.

Comment: I talked about *the input TeX source*, not the *output*. The first broken TeX thing in your comment was between the thirteenth and the fourteenth parenthesis, 6 characters for `\left(` times 14 = 84 characters.

Comment: @martin I know, strange isn't it. So Title, body and comments are all treated differently...

Comment: @martin how to see that is `0x200c` and friends?

Comment: I copy-pasted the offending text into my shell which displays unsupported characters as hex strings. If yours doesn't do that, you probably need some text editor capable of displaying hex, I don't know of an online solution.

Comment: @draks, use the MathJax contextual menu to view the MathML code (not the TeX code).  You will see the character entities (like `&#x200B;`) in the `<mtext>` tag inside the `<merror>`.  This holds the original markup, and so shows the extra characters there.

Comment: @DavideCervone thx that's great. Now I know what it's good for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of invisible characters that were inadvertently copied between the `r` and the `i` of `right`. `0x200C` (Zero Width Space Non-Joiner) and `0x200B` (Zero Width Space) from what I can see.

Whatever processing the source page went through converted the `0x200C` (Zero Width Space Non-Joiner) in the title to a real space:

> Invisible $\LaTeX$ error: $\mathrm{Im} \left( \right) $ vs. $\mathrm{Im} \left( \r ​ight) $

Comment: ok, but do you think that mats put'em there (in the comment) to break his own tex?

Comment: How can I see that?

Comment: what about the difference in body and title?

Comment: @draks...: these invisible spaces seem to be added by the web server or Ajax when a string of more than 80 uninterrupted characters is input. This messes up MathJax which does not simply delete them.

Comment: @draks...: it is hard to see, but when weird things happen to my LaTeX, I make sure there is at least 1 space every 79 characters.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are copying some hidden characters while at it. That would be the only plausible explanation.

Comment: ok, but do you think that mats put'em there (in the comment) to break his own tex?

Comment: No, but the line seems overly long, it might be an automatic linebreak or something which breaks the $\TeX$.